# Makes OpenVPN a local Apache Webserver accessable from outside?

Tags: web-server, vpn, apache-httpd, web-browsers, web

I am running Apache on my Pi. It's only accessable from my local network. Now I want to install OpenVPN on the same Pi.

**Is Apache accessable from outside, when I enter the static ip in my browser (the ip for OpenVPN)?**

**Does local Apache work as a "public webserver" after installing OpenVPN?**

This is, because my Apache should only be accessable from my local network. Not from outside.

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN is the service that is allowing you to connect from outside to your local network, basically a VPN server.

By connecting to it, it creates a tunnel and your traffic is routed through it, and have access to your local network through the internet. **The internal services, as in this case a HTTP Server, that you have on your network are not forwarded by OpenVPN through the public IP**, these resources can be accessed only if you have an active VPN connection and only on the internal IP.

In addition to that, if you are behind a router, you have to configure [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)!  on your router in order to be able to access the OpenVPN server from the internet, usually the Internet Providers are not closing the VPN ports, if you have issues, you can contact them and ask.

If your Internet Provider is assigning you a [dynamic IP Address](https://whatismyipaddress.com/dynamic-static)!, you have to configure a dynamic DNS in order to be able to access your Public IP Address when it changes.